# iOS8: Request Other User's Locaiton

Tags: ios8, core-location, cllocationmanager

iOS8 --

Using my app, UserA would like to request the location of UserB.  Each User would have their own device.

I think I should implement it as the following:

1. UserA requests UserB's location.
2. My server sends a Push Notification to UserB with a flag.
3. The flag calls a function that checks for permission and notifies UserB that UserA is requesting their location.
4. If UserB agrees, UserB's current location is collected and sent to my REST server which then forwards it to UserA.

Is their a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Push Notifications to alert your UserB of UserA's request, but don't forget:
**Push notifications are NOT reliable**.
They can be delayed or no received at all.

Once UserB opens his app (after seeing the notification for example), your app should check with your server to know what's up.

You should not use Push notifications for important functional purposes.